# Move input value and image to another page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in JavaScript and I need to move input value and image to another page after form submitting. I've looked many solutions of how people try to do it but I can't make it due to my code difficulty and difference between them.

I don't mind if you write the answer in jQuery but I might prefer the JavaScript code.

Here's my code:

```js
var getdata = document.getElementById('get-information')

function nameselect() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name-name')
  if(name.style.display == '') {
    name.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    name.style.display = '';
  }
};

function selectname(elementId) {
  var nameoutput = document.getElementsByClassName('nameselect')[0];
  nameoutput.value = elementId.innerText;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', Submit);

function Submit(event) {
  getdata.style.display = 'block';
  
  var nameoutput = document.getElementsByClassName('nameselect')[0];
  document.getElementById('naame1').textContent = nameoutput.value;
  
  event.preventDefault();
  
  form.reset();
  return false;
}
var loadimage = function(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      var output = document.getElementById('photos')
      output.src = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
```

```css
input, #name-name {
  display:inline-flex;
}
#name-name {
  display:none;
}
#name-list {
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

#files {
  display:block;
  margin-top:10px;
}
button {
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  color:#FFFAFA;
  background:#181716;
  display:block;
  margin-top:10px;
}
#get-information {
  display:none;
}
#photos {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:5px;
  }
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" class="nameselect" placeholder="Select your name" readonly="readonly" onclick="nameselect()">
  
  <div id="name-name">
    <div id="name-list">
      <div id="name-list-item" onclick="selectname(this);">Mike</div>
      <div id="name-list-item" onclick="selectname(this);">Lewis</div>
      <div id="name-list-item" onclick="selectname(this);">Max</div>
      <div id="name-list-item" onclick="selectname(this);">Ben</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <input type="file" id="files" onchange="loadimage(event)" multiple>
  <button type="submit" id="button">Send image</button>
</form>

<div id="get-information">
  <h4 id="naame1"></h4>
  <image id="photos" class="list-image" src="#"></image>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I hope following answer will help you

I have used Local Storage to load submited values in another html file.

Please do the following stpes

**Step 1:** Create/update the **./index.html** file with the following HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <!-- Call style sheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Form -->
        <form id="form">
            <input type="text" class="nameselect" placeholder="Select your name" readonly="readonly" onclick="nameselect()">
            
            <div id="name-name">
                <div id="name-list">
                    <div id="name-list-item" onclick="selectname(this);">Mike</div>
                    <div id="name-list-item" onclick="selectname(this);">Lewis</div>
                    <div id="name-list-item" onclick="selectname(this);">Max</div>
                    <div id="name-list-item" onclick="selectname(this);">Ben</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <input type="file" id="files" multiple>
            <button type="submit" id="button">Send image</button>
        </form>

        <!-- Script -->
        <script>
            var getdata = document.getElementById('get-information');

            // check exiting name from local storage__
            if(!window.localStorage.getItem('name')){
                window.localStorage.setItem('name', null);
            }
            
            // check exiting imageURL from local storage__
            if(!window.localStorage.getItem('imageurl')){
                window.localStorage.setItem('imageurl', null);
            }

            // when user focus the input field, displayname listed block
            function nameselect() {
                var name = document.getElementById('name-name')
                if(name.style.display == '') {
                    name.style.display = 'block';
                } else {
                    name.style.display = '';
                }
            };

            // create function for name select __
            function selectname(elementId) {
                // update name into local storage
                window.localStorage.setItem('name', elementId.innerText);
            }

            // reade image url from input file__
            var loadimage = function(event) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function() {
                    // set image in to local storage
                    window.localStorage.setItem('imageurl', reader.result);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
            };

            // create function for form submition__
            function Submit(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                form.reset();
                window.open("./preview.html", "_self");
            }

            // call form submition function__
            form.addEventListener('submit', Submit);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Step 2: Create **./preview.html** file with the following HTML code

This file used to preview the submited value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
        <!-- Call style sheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Back Link -->
        <a href="./index.html"> Back </a>

        <!-- Preview localstorage details -->
        <div id="preview-information">
            <h4 id="naame1"></h4>
            <image id="photos" class="list-image" src="#"></image>
        </div>

        <!-- Script -->
        <script>
            var imageURL = window.localStorage.getItem('imageurl');
            var nameValue = window.localStorage.getItem('name');

            document.getElementById('naame1').textContent = nameValue;
            document.getElementById('photos').src = imageURL;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Step 3:** Create/update **./styles.css** file with following css code

This css code was given by you, I didn't change this code.

```
input, #name-name {
    display:inline-flex;
  }
  #name-name {
    display:none;
  }
  #name-list {
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid #000;
  }
  
  #files {
    display:block;
    margin-top:10px;
  }
  button {
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    color:#FFFAFA;
    background:#181716;
    display:block;
    margin-top:10px;
  }
  #get-information {
    display:none;
  }
  #photos {
      width:300px;
      height:auto;
      border-radius:5px;
}
```

Try with above mention code, need any help let me know..

Thanks

Comment: it works but the image in the second page is not shown as well. I opened the code in Google and it shows to me that this one has a null URL. Console log gives me an error: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND".